# Excel autocomplete/ suggestion list. Not a drop down

Tags: microsoft-excel, autocomplete

I am using Excel to record various data and some rows have more cells than others. 
How can I make a list of words for Excel to use to autocomplete when I am entering data manually.

I don't need a drop down

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Jack. This is not a service site, rather a site for specific Q&A when you have attempted something and get stuck. Please expound on what you have tried so far and we will try to help from there. ***[ask]*** may be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Also, is AutoComplete enabled in your options?

Comment: Agree with CharlieRB. As a solution, the only thing I can think of is making a predefined list, f.e. in column A and hide the rows that contain the data. You'll notice that in the cells in that column, you'll have autocomplete. Just make sure you don't have empty cells in between them, that will break autocomplete functionality.

Comment: Watch this Video: [Autocomplete Entries With Excel Drop Down List](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOOuSe_s6pQ). Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You need an add-in to complete that. I guess this video is what you exactly need [Excel Autocomplete video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB7aedJ9RVI)

The website of the addin is https://www.excelautocomplete.com/. There are demonstrations on the site also.

This is how it works, you create a range which contain the list of items you want to appear in the suggestion list. Then, you select the cells which you want to enable the autocomplete feature and select the range you set up before. After this, all the selected cells now have drop down box appears on focus.

Comment: Added. However, it is hard to fully describe how the add-in works with just text

Comment: Much better, merci for taking my avice!